# Hang up codes asterisk

Tags: java, asterisk, agi

I am using asterisk for making outbound PSTN calls. We are using BSNL PRI Line, and dahdi. Recently we are facing some problems with the call hang ups, actually we have 30 channels but when we use more than 15 channels some calls are abnormally terminating, so I just want to know any agi method where we can retrieve the reason for the call hang up i.e by the network, user or system fault etc. Please suggest me any software or hardware changes to improve system capability to handle 30 calls, Software upgrading or LAN cable issues etc, I am ready to make any changes, Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

Any asterisk system(except embeded installation maybe) able handle 30 channels if propertly configure.

You can check variable PRI_CAUSE to got exactly pri cause.

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+variable+PRI_CAUSE

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, Can you please suggest me any agi or manager api methods to get PRI_CAUSE because I have to Handle them from java application.

Comment: AGI->get_variable("PRI_CAUSE")

Comment: Thanks a lot its working, but for HANGUP_CAUSE its working and PRI_CAUSE its giving null

Comment: Do AGI->exec("Dumpchan") and see in asterisk console all variables

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you're using Asterisk 11 you might consider attaching a hangup_handler to the calling channel and then checking the Hangup Cause in the handler.

See https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Hangup+Cause

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, Can you please suggest me any agi or manager api methods to get PRI_CAUSE because I have to Handle them from java application.